# Supremum and Infinmum of function with singularity

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, singularity-theory

[image]

My original approach was to let $f = \sin (1/x)$ and do regular calculus. However, I found that it wasn't so simple. I graphed the function on Mathematica and it was even worse!

It seems like the function tends to infniity near the origin (or negative infinity?) IN either case, I don't think it is bounded above nor does a supermum exist because of the singularity.

Any insights?

Comment: Let $t=1/x$ and begin with the observation: $0<\sin t<1/2$ if and only if either $2\pi n <t< \pi/3+2\pi n$ or $2\pi/3 + 2\pi n <t< \pi+2\pi n$. What is the corresponding range of $x$ in each case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inf is -1/pi, sup does not exist